# Opening date/time picker programatically in Material UI library

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm doing a project which uses React and Material Design.
I'd like to go with [Material UI](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui), as I need fancy Dat- and Time Pickers, which this Library supplies as components.

As I have to set Start- and End-Times and -Dates in a particular step in the app, I'd like to "hop" from one Picker to the next to decrease the Clicks the User has to make, i.e.

- Click on "Start Date" Input field
- Picker opens, Date gets selected
- The closing of the first Picker should open the **next** Picker (Start Time)
- Closing it opens the next Picker (End Date)
- Closing it opens the next Picker (End Time)

I know how to fire functions on those Events, but I don't know how to open the Pickers programmatically.

Tried a "dirty trick" with jQuery(...).click() or .focus() on the respective element, but it did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this problem adding `ref`  for each `datepicker`

```
handleChangeDPOne(){
  this.refs.datePickerTwo.openDialog()
}

handleChangeDPTwo(){
  // something
}

render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <DatePicker ref='datePickerOne' onChange={this.handleChangeDPOne} />
      <DatePicker ref='datePickerTwo' onChange={this.handleChangeDPTwo} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: thank you very much, I'll give it a shot and accept answer if it works!

Comment: How can this be done if the Datepicker is in a material table row which is generated dynamically?