# Close Date/Time Picker programmatically in Material UI Library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, material-ui

How to close Date/Time Picker programmatically in Material UI Library?

Comment: I assume you got downvotes because you haven't shared any code or context (your attempts so far etc) for your problem. Haven't tried it but this answer to a similar question may be interesting for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/39619803/4763083

Comment: At next time i will give some code.Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import React from 'react';
import DatePickerDialog from 'material-ui/DatePicker/DatePickerDialog';

export default class SomeComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.closeDatePicker = this.closeDatePicker.bind(this);
    this.openDatePicker = this.openDatePicker.bind(this);
  }

  closeDatePicker() {
    this.datePicker.dismiss();
  }

  openDatePicker() {
    this.datePicker.show();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.openDatePicker}>Open</button>
        <button onClick={this.closeDatePicker}>Close</button>
        <DatePickerDialog ref={ref => this.datePicker = ref} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work `autoOk={true}`. For more info, see this [github](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/1651) issue

Answer (score 0):

autoOk={true}

You can pass this prop in your component to close Popup just after date selection.

Answer (score 0):

The library i am using is **MobileDatePicker**

```
import MobileDatePicker from '@mui/lab/MobileDatePicker'
```

So you need to pass **disableCloseOnSelect** prop with boolean value as shown below to close the datepicker autoatically when user selects the date

```
<MobileDatePicker
   disableCloseOnSelect={false}             
/>
```